# My Scene turns blank and gray when I turn on Post Porcessing from the dropdown

Tags: post-processing

My Post processing worked when i started my project but now that i am several months into it, my scene view turns blank and gray when i check the post processing from the dropdown. I am using Unity 2019.4 Any ideas? My first posting was deleted because of clarity without notifying me, so I have been stuck on project for days waiting for an answer that was never going to come. I don't know how much more I can say. I you don't understand my post then don't just delete it, let me know what you don't understand.

Comment: Can you please show some details?

Comment: Is everything up to date (Unity, post processing, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like i may have fixed it. I got an error message saying that it couldn't add another camera, so i looked at the FPS. I didn't see anything wrong so I just removed it and reinstalled the FPS controller. That seems to have fixed it. Thanks for the responses.